# How to detect if mobile browser CAN install Flash?

Tags: javascript, flash, mobile-safari

I've run across several websites, including mine, that prompt users to download Flash even though their browser cannot install it. I want to avoid this confusing messaging by detecting whether a mobile browser **can** install Flash, not whether it **has** Flash.

Some known mobile browsers that can't install Flash are:

- iOS Safari
- Android Chrome beta
- Android Firefox

Instead of building an ever-changing list of Flash installability, I would like to detect this in a general way in Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "does your browser support potential extension X" feature in any browser engine.

I belive the only option is to build a list of known good user agents

- Some Android devices support Flash
- These devices do not expose when Flash could be installed
- Whitelist devices where Flash is known to run. This list should stay relatively small as Adobe will phase out mobile Flash soon.

Also, because the installation mechanism for mobile browser extensions is not standardized you cannot help users to install Flash on mobile.

Comment: It looks like very few mobile browsers support the Flash plugin - one being the default app called "Browser". But it's hard to do user agent detection on Browser. It has no distinguishing features.

Comment: At least Samsung Galaxy S identifies itself http://www.mobile-phone-specs.com/model/samsung_galaxy_ver1/ Maybe you should head here http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I did study the user agents of the various Android browsers. Chrome beta's distinguishing substring is "CrMo". Firefox's distinguishing substring is "Firefox". The default Browser has no distinguishing features. How safe is it to assume that when I do a bunch of `if-else` to catch the 3rd party browsers and reach the final `else`, that I'm left with Browser? This just feels hacky because there's so many 3rd party browsers that I have to add to my list - Dolphin, Opera, .... who knows ... maybe more?

Comment: I think the best assumption is that if it's mobile browser Flash installation is not possible. Mobile Flash is dying anyway - your solution would have max lifetime of one year.